# AKS TLS Using app service certificate/Key vault

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I have an Azure Kubernetes service running and want to secure my ingress's using an Azure App Service Certificate. I created a wild card certificate in Azure however the certificate does not seem to be available under certificates in the key vault which was configured when creating the cert. There is some sort of reference to the cert under secrets but I'm unsure of how to use this.

I deploy applications to my cluster using Helm. My Ingress controller is nginx and having read numerous tutorials I feel like all I am missing is the secret but unsure of the values to supply, ie the path.

```
kubectl create secret tls my-tls-secret --cert=[Unsure] --key=[Unsure]
```

My Helm chart QA values file looks like this:

```
ingress:
  hosts:
    - qa.[My domain].co.uk
  tls:
    - secretName: [Not created]
      hosts:
      - "qa.[My domain].co.uk"

probes:
  enabled: false
```

I have also installed cert manager on my cluster but unsure if this is required at this stage.

My main values file looks like this:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"  
  paths:
    - /
```

The app is currently redirecting to https as expected but obviously not secure as I am stuck on how to deploy my certificate.

Path to certificate and path to key file seem to be my main sticking points as I'm not sure of the syntax/location of these files.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Looks like it is possible anyway - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/export-your-app-service-certificate-to-any-azure-service/